# how to implement unsigned 33 bit integer type

Tags: c++, g++

Is there any way to implement 33 bit unsigned integer for gcc compiler? As of now I am using unsigned 64 bit integer to store 33 bit value. But unfortunately i want the value to be reset after it reaches full 33 bits...

Comment: I wonder why you would even need that...

Answer (score 13):

You could use a bit field, e.g. ([result](http://www.ideone.com/x16oL))

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdio>

struct uint33_t {
    uint64_t value : 33;
};

int main() {
    uint33_t x = {0x1FFFFFFFFull};

    printf("%llx\n", x.value);

    x.value += 1;

    printf("%llx\n", x.value);


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bit fields of data types than `int`, `signed int` and `unsigned int` are compiler-specific extensions, but GCC supports it so +1 anyway :-)

Comment: @Christoffer: It's not an extension. The C++ standard allows any "integral or enumeration type" (§[class.bit]/3) to be used as the bit-field type.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct int33
{
   unsigned long long x:33;
};
```

?

Answer (score 2):

The value will overflow when it is pushed beyond the 33-bit boundary; if you use a 33-bit mask when fetching the value you should get the behavior you want.

Comment: Translated: Use the native 64 bit datatype, and only use 33 bits of it when reading.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code dealing with this:

http://bitbucket.org/pnathan/logic-vector

You are free to look it over. If you modify/improve it please patch back. :)